# How to get user account on window phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Could you tell me how to get user's email on window phone 8.For example, I want to get Google email account email or Microsoft email account (ex abc@gmail.com or abc@live.com) if user have setting.

Answer (score 1):

You can not get any information about an user of a Windows Phone device. You will have to ask the user for his/her email yourself.

Comment: oh,so it can not get email adreess?because I think user setting email on window phone and we can get email adress?

Comment: No, you can not. It could be very, very, abused.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the users email without asking the user for this information within the app. If you want some other way to identify the user you could use the DeviceExtendedProperties to get a unique identifier for the user:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.deviceextendedproperties(v=vs.105).aspx